# Creating a JSON Cloud Formation Template with an EC2 Instance that also attaches EBS volume...

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, cloud

I am pretty new to programming in general... so Excuse me if my question is very broad as I honestly have no idea what I am doing. Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide information on what you have tried so far and what you have an issue with exactly. Broad and open questions like this are likely gonna be flagged for closure before you get any helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Going off what I've seen on some training videos online; this is what I have as my base/foundation of the template... Am I on the right track? I honestly have no idea what I'm doing ... :(

```
AWS::EC2::Instance

{

    "Resources" : {`enter code here`
        "AWSCloudFormationTemplate" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        }
    }
}

{
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
    "Availability Zone" : String,
    "BlockDeviceMappings" : [EC2 Block Device Mapping, ...],
    "Disabled ApiTermination" : Boolean,
    "Ebsptimized" : Boolean,
    "IamInstanceProfile" : String,
    "ImageId" : String,
    "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior" : String,
    "InstanceType" : String,
    "KernelId" : String,
    "KeyName" : String,
    "Monitoring" : Boolean,
    "NetworkInterfaces" : [ EC2 Network Interface, ...],
    "PlacementGroupName" : String,
    "PrivateIpAddress" :  String,
    "RamdiskId" : String,
    "SecurityGroupIds" : [ String, ...],
    "SecurityGroups" : [String, ...],
    "SourceDestCheck" : Boolean,
    "SubnetId" :  String,
    "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ...],
    "Tenancy" : String,
    "UserData" : String,
    "Volumes" : [EC2 MountPoint, ...],
    "AdditionalInfo" : String

    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **BlockDeviceMappings** This snipped would create instance with dedicated 200Gb SSD volume:

```
      "MASTER" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "Tags":[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"MASTER"}],
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : "mykey",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                 {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                        "Ebs": {
                            "VolumeSize": "200",
                            "VolumeType": "io1",
                            "Iops": "2000"
                            }
                        }
                ],
        "ImageId" : "ami-a25415cb",
        "InstanceType": "m1.large"
      }
      }
```